# Laravel 5.1 (Eloquent) in using relationship attaching or detaching not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I'm having problems in using Laravel 5.1's Eloquent. I have 2 databases, and 2 model classes are using a different database (that is not default database).
It is working well for simple CRUD, but when I use relationship, it causes an error.

```
$list->users()->attach($nListUser->id, [
                            'entered' => $user->createdDate,
                            'modified' => date('Y-m-d H:m:s'),
                            ]);
```

Or

```
$list->users()->detach($nListUser->id);
```

Error code is

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'sampledb.listuser' doesn't exist (SQL: insert
>   into `listuser` (`entered`, `listid`, `modified`, `userid`)
>   values (2012-06-17 18:34:58, 52275, 2016-01-18 02:01:46, 6))

This is my model class file.

```
class ListUser extends Model
{

    protected $connection = 'listdbconnection';
    protected $table = 'listuser';

    public $timestamps = false;

}
class PList extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'listdbconnection';
    protected $table = 'list';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\User', 'listuser', 'userid', 'listid');
    }
}
```

Eventhough I set connection name above, it is still finding the table in default database. It is clear that the Eloquent is working on default database for relationship.
Has anyone solution for this? Am I wrong or Is this really Laravel 5.1 Eloquent's fault?

Comment: if it's a relation between two different database, then laravel (eloquent or even query builder) won't do any good as far as i remember.

Comment: would you recommend me better one, please?

Comment: if you're able to fetch to your second database easily (without relations, or with relations that only within a single database) then i can't recommend anything better than a downright manual approach. some discussion [in this page](http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections) of its possible drawbacks. anyway, if you are unable to access your second database completely, [this article might shed some light](http://tutsnare.com/connect-multiple-databases-in-laravel/). anyway, i find [this](http://laravel.io/forum/02-12-2014-many-to-many-relationship-not-working-across-databases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the reason.
Eloquent was wonderful. The model class I specified in the belongsToMany parameter was wrong.
It was actually, as belows.

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\LUser', 'listuser', 'userid', 'listid');
```

I recommend Eloquent because you can use it outside Laravel. Maybe, good choice for web service development.